# How can I create test values with a left skew distribution and a given median and interquartile range?

Tags: r, testing, distribution, median

I need test values (n =~400) with a left skew distribution and a given mean and interquartile range (median = 6000; IQR = 2800 to 12000)? Unfortunately, I have no idea how I can do this. Any ideas how I can create such values using R?

Comment: you could start at `help(distributions)`

Comment: Thanks, I found rlnorm this way. I think "rlnorm(200, meanlog=8.6, sdlog=1)" works.